# Android limit the no of items displayed in a spinner's dropdown list

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have a spinner item bound to an array adapter which might have 0 or more items at any time. I want the spinner dropdown list to only show three items at a time, the rest of the items being scrollable.
I have tried wrapping the spinner within a layout with a fixed width but the spinner drop down list still takes up the entire screen(if there are that many items in the array adapter) to display the list.

Comment: I don't think there is a simple way way to do that without customizing your adapter. But maybe this can help: https://github.com/ankitthakkar/DropDownSpinner

Comment: how do you do it by customizing the adapter? i don't wanna make my own custom spinner item using a button and a list view as done in the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was looking at the `Spinner` source code and it seems like you can't do that with a spinner.

The `Spinner` has its own private interface called `SpinnerPopup` which defines how dropdown items can be shown. This is currently based on the [`spinnerMode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#attr_android%3aspinnerMode) allowing for a dropdown or dialog list.

Both options are also implemented inside the `Spinner` class as private classes: `DialogPopup` and `DropdownPopup`. Since you can't access them, it seems to me your only options at this point are:

1. Implement your own custom spinner based on other widgets such as in [this example](https://github.com/ankitthakkar/DropDownSpinner).
2. [Copy the code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/2888524e03896831f487e5dee63f18f1c33c0115/core/java/android/widget/Spinner.java) from the `Spinner` class which seems pretty self-contained and implement your version of a spinner with it, modifying whatever you like in it.

I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Good luck!

EDIT:

If you choose option 2, I think all you need to do is add your mode implementing the `SpinnerPopup` interface. Then inside the constructor `Spinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle, int mode)` add another `case` to the `switch` checking for the modes to instantiate your own popup. Doesn't seem hard.

Comment: i think i will go with the second option..sounds easier!

Comment: Come back here with the results later. :)

Comment: where did you download the source code?i used the following link`http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/Spinner.java`(realized later on that it was the source code from way back 2009)..removed almost everything that showed error and in the onClick function i set the width and height of the spinner dialog box(no popup in android 1.5) which worked!

Comment: Cool!! I got the code from the SDK manager, you can download it for the different API versions there. Then you just have to attach it: stackoverflow.com/a/16433131/362298

Comment: Hello pls help.. I am using same lib Is there any way to setText to spinner onItemClick

Comment: _state = state[position];
    System.out.println(_state+">>>>>>>>>>>>>");

    _select_state_btn.setText(_state);

Answer (score 2):

### This answer doesn't work anymore, please look elsewhere.

---

> Here's the ultimately simple solution.. just copy this line in Spinner
> tag...
>
> ```
> android:dropDownHeight="100dp"    <!--change 100dp to your requirement-->
> ```
>
> you can also modify width...
>
> ```
> android:dropDownWidth="100dp"   <!--change 100dp to your requirement-->
> ```
>
> and you know what it works on `AutoCompleteTextView` too and with
> atleast api 16...

Comment: This is very bad solution because font sizes can rendered different sizes in different phones , height must not be hard coded consider using my solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56163333/5629011

Comment: android:dropDownHeight has no effect

Comment: android:dropDownHeight doesn't supported it seems

Answer (score 0):

The recommended solutions are not really interesting because they hard code the height of drop down this is bad because font size are actually different in different phones, I handled it dynamic and reliable like this :

```java
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drop_down_text_view,
                new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}) {

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                TextView dropDownTextView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                dropDownTextView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        myDropDownMenuOrSpinnerOrAutoCompleteTextView.setDropDownHeight(dropDownTextView.getHeight() * 3);

                        dropDownTextView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    }
                });
                return dropDownTextView;
            }
        };
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work as I couldn't find a setDropDownHeight method on any type of related view. Did you create a custom spinner class?

Comment: @szaske Just set it to your spinner height. I was using autoCompleteTextView which had this method.