# Why is the Spinner's interface SpinnerPopup private? Why can't I add my own popup view?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-spinner

I was looking at a way to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238513/android-limit-the-no-of-items-displayed-in-a-spinners-dropdown-list/) where the OP is trying to limit the number of items displayed in the spinner's dropdown view. It seems that it cannot be done.

The `Spinner` class has its own private interface called `SpinnerPopup` which defines how dropdown items can be shown. This is currently based on the [`spinnerMode`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html#attr_android:spinnerMode) allowing for a dropdown or dialog list.

Both options are also implemented inside the Spinner class as private classes: `DialogPopup` and `DropdownPopup`. So it seems to me that the only way to customize this to add another popup option would be to copy the [spinner source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/2888524e03896831f487e5dee63f18f1c33c0115/core/java/android/widget/Spinner.java) and create my own version of it.

But if the `SpinnerPopup` interface were public, it seems like it would be easy to just:

1. Create my own popup implementing `SpinnerPopup`; and
2. Create my own spinner extending the original one where I override the constructor `Spinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle, int mode)` to handle my popup.

Does anyone have any idea (or guess) why this is not the case? Or am I missing a simpler solution here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I need set my own view to the dropdown, so this was what I did:

```
public class SpinnerAdapter_Tabela_Preco extends ArrayAdapter<Tabela_Preco>{ 

    // Your sent context
    private Context context;
    private List<Tabela_Preco> list_tabela_preco;

    public SpinnerAdapter_Tabela_Preco(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Tabela_Preco> values) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.list_tabela_preco = values;
    }

    public int getCount(){
       return list_tabela_preco.size();
    }

    public Tabela_Preco getItem(int position){
       return list_tabela_preco.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position){
       return position;
    }


    // And the "magic" goes here
    // This is for the "passive" state of the spinner
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Tabela_Preco t_p = getItem(position);

        // I created a dynamic TextView here, but you can reference your own  custom layout for each spinner item
        TextView label = new TextView(context);
        label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        label.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

        // Then you can get the current item using the values array (Users array) and the current position
        // You can NOW reference each method you has created in your bean object (User class)
        label.setText(t_p.toString());

        // And finally return your dynamic (or custom) view for each spinner item
        return label;
    }

    // And here is when the "chooser" is popped up
    // Normally is the same view, but you can customize it if you want
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Tabela_Preco t_p = getItem(position);

        TextView label = new TextView(context);
        label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        label.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        label.setMinimumHeight(50);
        label.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        label.setTextSize(18);
        label.setText(t_p.toString());

        return label;
    }
}
```

And I use with this:

```
final SpinnerAdapter_Tabela_Preco adapter = new    SpinnerAdapter_Tabela_Preco(Consulta_Produto.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lista_tabela_preco);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spn_tabela_preco.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I hope this could help you.

Comment: Hi William, thanks. I am aware of the `getView` and `getDropDownView` but these customize the item views that go inside the popup. I want to customize all of the pop-up, including the `ListView` container itself, not only its items.

Comment: Hi Hw can i add padding to the label?