# Fix Display Items Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

Let's just say i had a spinner with 200 drop down items, when i click on it drop down comes with a vertical scroll and enough items[10-15 items] that fit according to the screen height, i want only 5 items to be displayed and rest selected by scrolling vertically. not 10 or 20 or 30 at once. 
What Attribute should i set?

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+tintdialog/TintSelector_Spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/dropdown_dynamic"

             />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix the height of your spinner:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+tintdialog/TintSelector_Spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/dropdown_dynamic"

             />
    </LinearLayout>
```

change height from `wrap_content` to `fixed` height;

I think it wont work:

check this answer: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238513/android-limit-the-no-of-items-displayed-in-a-spinners-dropdown-list)

Answer (score 0):

Change height to fixed sized instead of wrap content