# how to only display First 3 items in a spinner and other items by scrolling?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-spinner

So i have a spinner as you can see in the image

[image: Spinner Image]

So what i want to do is that i only want to display the first 3 items and rest items should be scroll-able. Any Ideas?

Comment: This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238513/android-limit-the-no-of-items-displayed-in-a-spinners-dropdown-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can adjust you spinner popup menu height like below:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    try {
        Field popup = Spinner.class.getDeclaredField("mPopup");
        popup.setAccessible(true);

        // Get private mPopup member variable and try cast to ListPopupWindow
        ListPopupWindow popupWindow = (ListPopupWindow) popup.get(spinner);
        popupWindow.setHeight(500);
    }
    catch (NoClassDefFoundError | ClassCastException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        // silently fail...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set this property to spinner in *xml*:

```
android:dropDownHeight="100dp"
```